# Novel about a group of people who are abducted by aliens and cloned

Tags: story-identification, clones, alien-abduction

I remember listening to an audio book years ago about a group of people who did not know each other who were abducted by aliens. That's rather generic, but the hook was that each one of the people had been cloned, and either the original or the clone had been put back into their normal lives with no memory of having been abducted. There was a helmet/VR goggles or something to that effect in the chamber with the people on the ship, which would allow them to see through the eyes of their clones back on Earth.

Additionally, one of the humans had 2 clones created; one was placed on Earth and the other was there in the ship. When either of those clones wore the helmet, she saw out of both of the other clones' (the one on Earth and the one on the ship) eyes at the same time, which was extremely disorienting.

That's all I really remember about the plot. I think there were a few worldbuilding pieces that have stuck in my brain (such as tigers that had been genetically engineered to be the size and temperament of house cats), but that's about it.

Does anyone recognize my description? Any clue what the book is?

Comment: Was it actual cloning or duplicative teleportation?  (Like in *The Resurrected Man*, *Farthest Star* or Simmon's *Illium*)

Comment: Have a look at [Novel about near future where humans are transmitted to a mirrored room on another planet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/206447/novel-about-near-future-where-humans-are-transmitted-to-a-mirrored-room-on-anoth) and see if that rings any bells. For example the mirrored room.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your description rang a bell: might it be "**[The Other End Of Time](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Other_End_of_Time_(novel))**" by Frederick Pohl?

In this novel, published in 1996, the main characters don't know each other prior to the current events, have been abducted by aliens and experience cloning, although here the original bodies are sent back to Earth and their clones are kept by the aliens.

Comment: Looks like that was it! A few minutes on google books brings up a few passages that are pretty familiar. I had no idea Pohl was still around in the 90's, much less still writing. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Pohl had a long career indeed! And this series, although below his best works, is still enjoyable nonetheless.